# Generate delete confirmation box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

In my application results are displaying as a table format.

Part of my code is,

```
{% for device in devices %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ device.operator}}</td>
    <td>{{ device.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ device.tstampgps }}</td>
    <td><button id='rec_delete'>Delete</button></td>

  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Even if we press the delete button, I need to delete the particular record from the database. before that I want to prompt a confirmation box for that. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have multiple `button id="rec_delete"` elements? Those should have unique IDs, and give them a class so you can more easily find them with a selector like `tr.device button.delete`. Then you can add a `click` listener with a `confirm()` and `return false` to cancel the delete. In fact, `return confirm('Delete?');` from the click handler should suffice.

Comment: can you give some sample code?

Comment: I added a slight but important change to the reference on the `$.click` which you should be aware when using an AJAX function (which will change scope, changing `this`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a unique record Identifier that you can associate to DB to the button. Once confirmed you send this identifier to server with AJAX and sever code does the DB delete. Also change ID to class on repeating elements since ID's must be unique

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ device.operator}}</td>
    <td>{{ device.state }}</td>
    <td>{{ device.tstampgps }}</td>
    <td><button class='rec_delete'  data-record_id="{{ device.DB_ID }}">Delete</button></td>

  </tr>
```

JS

```
$('button.rec_delete').click(function(){
     /* data() method reads the html5 data attribute from html */
     var record_id=$(this).data('record_id');

     if( confirm( 'Are you sure') ){
        $.post( 'serverPage.php', { id: record_id}, function(){
            /* code to run on ajax success*/
          $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        })
    }
})
```

Server will receive the post key `id` as you would with any other form element name

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know Django, this doesn't include the delete part, which I assume you will AJAXify that (do an asynchronous request to delete). I'm also showing the `$devices` and `$deletes` variables as local variables here separately, more or less so you can see how you can store references and then work from those references (which I believe is a better practice than reselecting over and over).

Note also the use of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function r($){
```

I'm using `jQuery()` in the global scope, which in a larger app you should always do to keep from conflicting with other libraries/frameworks which may use `$()`. This is also a best practice, and you can use `$()` within that anonymous function (closure). It's best to get used to doing it this way, IMO.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Operator</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>T-Stamp GPS</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="device">
            <td>Verizon</td>
            <td>OK</td>
            <td>033830928</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="d001" class="delete">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**NOTE**

I made a slight but important change, with reference to the `$self`, since the AJAX will run the `success` handler after `this` is out of scope:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function r($){
    var $devices = $('tr.device'),
        $deletes = $devices.find('button.delete');

    $deletes.click(function d(){
        var $self = $(this).parents('tr.device'),
            del = confirm('Delete device?');

        if (del) {
            // Do $.ajax() request, maybe using the 
            // clicked button's ID. Or you could put
            // the row to delete ID on the TR element.
            // And then on success of the AJAX, run:
            $self.fadeOut(500, function f(){
                $self.remove();
            });
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wMqr8/2

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event to your JavaScript, and if the user chooses the "ok" button, you can send a request to the view that takes care of removing the record or whatever

Comment: If we press the button on a particular record, how to take that record data in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button id='rec_delete' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Button placed on a table here, when we press delete button I need to take the particular record value. how can I do that?